# no internet connection in VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop in VirtualBox and host OS is also same. I have set VirtualBox network settings to Bridge Adapter, but still I am not able to connect to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I got the answer.
I tried lot of things but nothing worked for me when I was using company WiFi. But when I tried same thing on different network, it started working.
It seems like company router has blocked virtual requests.